# Push после pull --rebase

Tags: git, git-push, git-rebase, git-pull

Допустим, я сделал `git pull --rebase`, в результате чего мой(-и) коммит(-ы) переместились вверх, сдвинув указатель («ветку»).

После того, как я сделаю `git push`, станет ли удаленная ветка такой же, как и локальная?

Comment: если при ребейзе не поменялись старые коммиты (то есть был fastforward, о чем git pull напишет), то ответ да, будет такой же как локальная.

Comment: @KoVadim так с `--rebase` он как раз старые коммиты оставит как есть, а все последующие сребейзит на верхушку этой ветки. Или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: если я правильно прочитал документацию, то git постарается так сделать, но всякое может случиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насколько я понимаю:

- **если** команда `pull --rebase` завершилась удачно (либо возникшие конфликты были устранены редактированием, добавлением файлов в индекс (`add ...`) и последующим выполнением `rebase --continue`)
- **если** команда `push` завершилась удачно (удалённая ветка за это время не «сдвигалась» благодаря добавлению новых коммитов или даже (частичному) переписыванию истории)
- **то** и ветка в вашем локальном, и ветка в удалённом репозитории будут указывать на один и тот же коммит. что гарантирует и полную идентичность всего дерева коммитов, для которых данный коммит является «верхушкой» (тем фактом, что в этих двух репозиториях история может иметь разную «глубину», в данном случае, думаю, можно пренебречь).